# Rest Assured Post request erase previous data

Tags: rest-assured

I am using json-server and have a dummy json. When i am adding a new student (say id=100) using post request. Every time it erase previous student (id=14) and then create new student.

Below is the payload.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "studname": null,
    "student": [
      {
        "name": "JJJ",
        "location": null,
        "phone": null,
        "courses": null,
        "id": 14
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my rest assured code which i am running through eclipse:

```java
@Test
public void addStudentData() {
  StudentList Studentdetails = new StudentList();

  StudentsDetails mainDetails = new StudentsDetails();
  mainDetails.setName("JJJ");
  mainDetails.setId(15);

  List < StudentsDetails > details = new ArrayList < StudentsDetails > ();

  details.add(mainDetails);

  Studentdetails.setStudent(details);

  given()
    .contentType("application/json")
    .body(Studentdetails)
    .when()
    .post(EndPoints.CREATE_STUDENTS)
    .then()
    .extract().response().asString();
}
```

output: Status 201

```json
"data": {
  "studname": null,
  "student": [
    {
      "name": "James",
      "location": null,
      "phone": null,
      "courses": null,
      "id": 101
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No, Rest-Assured CANNOT do that. Please check your service or your code.

Comment: Its not very clear what is the problem.

Comment: I believe you're not using your endpoint in the proper way or using wrong endpoint. Basically what you pass to your endpoint is not a student but a list of students. So it probably just replaces the previous list with the new one